# Were Etruscan words such as "avil" (year) and "sum" (foot, measurement of length) singularia tantum or pluralia tantum?

Tags: noun, plural, etruscan, singular

Were Etruscan words such as "avil" (year) and "sum" (foot, measurement of length) singularia tantum or pluralia tantum? Would adjectives applied to them be declined in singular or in plural? Or would that depend on the context?

Would "*it was a hot year*" be "*Amuce ermaniar avil.*" or "*Amuce ermania avil.*"? Would "*There were seven fertile years.*" be "*Amuce semph crepni avil.*" or "*Amuce semph crepniar avil.*"?

Would "*These two shoes are for small feet.*" be "*Zal tetinar cleri am mevelceari sumi eri.*" or "*Zal tetinar cleri am mevelcei sumi eri.*"? Was "*sum*" (locative, required by the postposition "*eri*", presumably being "*sumi*") even a proper form for "*feet*" when referring to body parts rather than the unit of length, or was it "*sumar*" (proper plural, so that the locative would be "*sumari*") when referring to body parts?